# Can I debug Javascript from FlashDevelop?

Tags: javascript, flashdevelop, haxe, openfl

I'm developing for a JS target in Haxe using FlashDevelop.  I would like to be able from inside the IDE, in the same way I debug a Flash target, with the breakpoints, callstack, variable list, all showing up in the IDE.

I currently use source maps with Chrome, but some IDE's can tie into Chrome directly to enable the debugging to happen in the IDE directly.

Is this possible in Flash Develop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not currently possible. But FlashDevelop is open source so you are free to add this functionality yourself.